# Bash Script not working when trying to find large ASCII files

Tags: bash, while-loop, find

So what I'm trying to do is find large ASCII files and then print out the name of the file and then how many lines, but when I start my script it doesn't find anything.

`find / -type f -size +2000c -exec file {} \; 2>/dev/null | awk -F':' '/: ASCII text/ {print $1}' | while read FILENAME; do LINES="$(wc -l)"; if [ $LINES > 10000 ]; then echo $FILENAME && echo $LINES; fi; done`

Comment: `LINES="$(wc -l)"` doesn't read from `"$FILENAME"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you got wrong?

`if [ $LINES > 10000 ]` here `>` goes for a string comparison. To use a numberic comparion `-gt` must be used as

`if [ $LINES -gt 10000 ]`

Comment: It's still not finding anything even after that change.

Comment: why dont you use `wc` instead?

Comment: `if [ $LINES > 10000 ]; then ...` will happily leave your current directory with an empty file called `10000`, since `>` doesn't go for a string comparison, but for a redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
find / -type f -size +2000c -print0 | xargs.exe -0 grep -Z -L -e '[^[:print:]]' 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 awk 'ENDFILE { if (FNR > 10000) { print FILENAME " " FNR } }'
```

The idea is to filter out binary files with *grep* and feed *awk* with the list of filtered files to finally filter out files with line count less or equal to 10000.

btw, it handles files with white space in names gracefully.